# Command to re-run script from within the script in python

Tags: python

Still working on my hangman game! I'd like to define a function which re-runs the whole python script - i.e. which resets the word to be guessed, the number of blank spaces, the letters guessed and the hangman diagram - if 'yes' is called as its argument. I've tried using the built-in execfile() function, but this only adds blanks or removes letters if the new word is of a different length to the previous:

```
In [17]: attempt(word, 'r')
u n d e r  

a b c - - f g h i j k - m - o p q - s t - v w x y z
  _________
 ||       |
 ||
 ||       
 ||
 ||
 ||
 ||_________

Congratulations! You guessed the correct word!

Would you like to play again?
```

is the result of the previous game, and when I write

```
In [18]: play_again('yes')

In [19]: word = ['a','c','e']

In [20]: guess(word)
>>>       _________
         ||       |
         ||
         ||       
         ||
         ||
         ||
         ||_________

In [21]: attempt(word, 'a')
```

I get

```
a n d  

- b c - - f g h i j k - m - o p q - s t - v w x y z
  _________
 ||       |
 ||       0
 ||     /( )\
 ||
 ||
 ||
 ||_________
```

which shows that, while the guess() function seems to reset fine after playing again, the rest of the code stays the same apart from the length of word to be guessed. The subprocess() function had a similar effect/didn't work either, from what I remember. Is there a simple way to re-run the whole script so that it's all reset?

Don't know if the whole script is needed for you to provide me an answer (and I don't know if it's stupid of me to not include it), so if you need it all I'll edit this post, but thought I'd keep it as short as possible by not including it all and just including the play_again function for the moment. Hope this is all clear!

play_again function:

```
def play_again(decision=''):
if decision == 'yes':
    execfile("C:\Users\Joel\Documents\Year 1\Labs\Computing\Learning\hangmanglobal.py")
if decision == 'no':
    print "Thank you for playing Hangman!"
```

Comment: You should solve this with a `while` loop rather than calling `execfile`. Have your main program (including the initializiation of variables) in a `while True` loop which breaks when the user decides to end the game.

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this with a `while` loop which breaks once the user wants to stop. using `execfile` for this is rather awkward and will break if you move the script around.

Pseudo-code:

```
while True:
    # initialize variables
    # redraw your graphics
    # play the game
    # ask user if he wants to play another game
    if not play_again:
        break

print('Thanks for playing, bye')
```

Preferably you should call functions for the steps outlined above, in order to not have a giant `while` loop.